# How to prove that $4n^2+4n+8$ is even?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

I'm trying to prove that $4n^2+4n+8$ is even. I tried dividing the polynomial by $2n$ to get a remainder of $8$. Is this correct? how do I proceed ?

Comment: It's divisible by 4, hence by 2.

Comment: It is easy . Let us suppose it is even for k . Then we can prove it is divusible by k+1 by mathematical induction.

Comment: Or by observation it is seen that from equation $4n^2+4n+8$ we can remove out 2 as a common factor. Hence it is multiple of 2 thus number is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An even number looks like $2n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Can't you see a way to do that?

$$4n^2 + 4n + 8 = 2(2n^2 + 2n + 2*2)$$
You wrote the polynomial as $2$ times a natural number. So, it is even.

Answer (score 1):

Any number is said to even when it is divisible by $2$

Given that $$4n^2+4n+8=2(2n^2+2n+4)=2\lambda $$
where, $\lambda$ is some integer

Above, number $2\lambda$ is even i.e. $4n^2+4n+8$ is even number.